# Legend widget not loading all layers on inital load esri javascript api 3.20

Tags: legend, widget, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

When using the legend widget (esri JAPI 3.20), not all the layers show up when my map loads. I have to zoom a level first then they all show up. Any fixes?

Comment: Is there any scale range set on your layers? How do you add the widget? Could you show your code?

Comment: there is a scale range on a few but thats not the ones not showing up.

Comment: var legend = new Legend({
   map: map,
   layerInfos: layers,
            
  }, "legendDiv");
    
  legend.startup();